# Broadband account getting locked if multiple machines used

Tags: broadband

I have subscribed to a broadband Internet connection provided by a local cable TV provider.

Normally, I use my laptop which has Windows 7 for light surfing. I have set up a Broadband connection(PPPoE) for the same as per the provider's instructions.

The issue arises when I remove the cable from my laptop and plug it into my desktop and try to use it by setting up a connection there,too. My account either gets locked immediately or even if it connects, when I connect the cable back to my laptop, it appears surely locked. Then I have to call up the provider to unlock it :(

I'm sure that the provider is storing something on each machine and disallowing use of multiple machines. This is a real disadvantage as I can't download overnight by using my desktop.

Please guide as to how I must get rid of this inconvenience.

Thanks and regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because the connection is tied to the [MAC Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_address) of the network card. If the cable modem has a USB port you could try that option to connect to a USB port on the PC and laptop - you may have to install the drivers on the laptop and PC.

Another option you could try (if any of the systems have two network cards) is to setup [ICS (Internet Connection Sharing)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing). ICS can also be setup in the scenario of USB connected cable modem + single network card.